# CMemDC class issue

Tags: c++, bitmap, mfc

Here is the following CMemDC class I am using from code projects that supposedly fixes the flickering:

```
#ifndef _MEMDC_H_
#define _MEMDC_H_

#include "stdafx.h"

namespace MemoryDC
{
    class CMemDC : public CDC {
    private:
        CBitmap     m_bitmap;       // Offscreen bitmap
        CBitmap*    m_oldBitmap;    // bitmap originally found in CMemDC
        CDC*        m_pDC;          // Saves CDC passed in constructor
        CRect       m_rect;         // Rectangle of drawing area.
        BOOL        m_bMemDC;       // TRUE if CDC really is a Memory DC.
    public:

        CMemDC(CDC* pDC, const CRect* pRect = NULL) : CDC()
        {
            ASSERT(pDC != NULL);

            // Some initialization
            m_pDC = pDC;
            m_oldBitmap = NULL;
            m_bMemDC = !pDC->IsPrinting();

            // Get the rectangle to draw
            if (pRect == NULL) {
                pDC->GetClipBox(&m_rect);
            }
            else {
                m_rect = *pRect;
            }

            if (m_bMemDC) {
                // Create a Memory DC
                CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);
                pDC->LPtoDP(&m_rect);

                m_bitmap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(pDC, m_rect.Width(), m_rect.Height());
                m_oldBitmap = SelectObject(&m_bitmap);

                SetMapMode(pDC->GetMapMode());

                SetWindowExt(pDC->GetWindowExt());
                SetViewportExt(pDC->GetViewportExt());

                pDC->DPtoLP(&m_rect);
                SetWindowOrg(m_rect.left, m_rect.top);
            }
            else {
                // Make a copy of the relevent parts of the current DC for printing
                m_bPrinting = pDC->m_bPrinting;
                m_hDC = pDC->m_hDC;
                m_hAttribDC = pDC->m_hAttribDC;
            }

            // Fill background 
            FillSolidRect(m_rect, pDC->GetBkColor());
        }

        ~CMemDC()
        {
            if (m_bMemDC) {
                // Copy the offscreen bitmap onto the screen.
                m_pDC->BitBlt(m_rect.left, m_rect.top, m_rect.Width(), m_rect.Height(),
                    this, m_rect.left, m_rect.top, SRCCOPY);

                //Swap back the original bitmap.
                SelectObject(m_oldBitmap);
            }
            else {
                // All we need to do is replace the DC with an illegal value,
                // this keeps us from accidently deleting the handles associated with
                // the CDC that was passed to the constructor.          
                m_hDC = m_hAttribDC = NULL;
            }
        }

        // Allow usage as a pointer 
        CMemDC* operator->()
        {
            return this;
        }

        // Allow usage as a pointer 
        operator CMemDC*()
        {
            return this;
        }
    };
}
#endif
```

Here is my OnDraw function using above class:

```
void ViewerView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    MemoryDC::CMemDC dc(pDC);

    ViewerDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    
    if (!pDoc)
        return;
    else
        RenderPage(dc, 0);
}
```

And here is the OnEraseBkgnd function:

```
BOOL ViewerView::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

Here is the following video which best describes what is happening to my scrolling since a video is worth a thousand words

I tried double buffering and what not to fix this issue, but I am not having a good time.

If anyone has any suggestions or help much is appreciated.

Salute.

Comment: MFC already includes an, undocumented, memory DC class.

Comment: @zdf, yes I know that’s why I wrapped the class in a namespace to be able to use it as it was considered a redefinition. I just thought this edited class was going to fix the flickering issue as seen in the video as that what it stated on codeproject.

Comment: What the video shows is more like a scrolling issue; it does not look like a flickering issue.

Comment: @zdf, ah that’s one step forward for me at least, I will update this with my scrolling code then when I have time tomorrow.

Comment: You are looking for [CDC::ScrollDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdc-class?view=msvc-160#scrolldc).

Answer (score 1):

Do not reinvent the wheel.
MFC already has a memory DC class, you can easily use it like this:

```cpp
void ViewerView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    CRect rc;
    GetClientRect(&rc);
    CMemDC memDC(*pDC, rc);
    auto& rDC = memDC.GetDC();

    RenderPage(&rDC, 0);
}
```

As a sidenote:
If you don't want the system to erase the background for you every time, you should return `TRUE` from the `OnEraseBkgnd` function.

Comment: This doesn't address the question that is being asked, and doesn't offer a solution.